# Filter GridView with Dropdown List

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to filter my `GridView` with a dropdown list so that on only the results which are relevant to the selected dropdown item are shown. I've found quite a lot of examples for Sql Datasource, however I am using ObjectDataSource.

This is the code for my `GridView` and `Dropdown`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" >
     <asp:ListItem  Text="Person1" Value="Name"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Person2" Value="Name"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Person3" Value="Name"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Person4" Value="Name"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropdownList>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" >
     <PagerSettings  Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="30" />
     <PagerStyle CssClass="Pager" Font-Size="Large" Height="50px"/>
         <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="45%" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="85px" Width="40%" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Job" HeaderText="Department"  ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="" >
                 <ItemStyle Width="30%" HorizontalAlign="Center"  Height="85px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
         </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="Names"  SelectMethod="NamesData" />
```

So I want that if the user selects Person1 from the dropdown list the GridView will only display those results. Any suggestions are appreciated!

UPDATE

```
    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Person=" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    }
```

I've tried this but am getting the following error:

> System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Person' operator.

Comment: [ObjectDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.filterexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) has a `FilterExpression` string property. Can you simply just set that in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList`? Something like `ods.FilterExpression = "Name=" + ddl.SelectedValue;`

Comment: yeah I've tried that but nothing seems to be happening

Comment: Share your actual code behind. ASP markup is great and all to get an idea what the page looks like, but without seeing how you're configuring the filter expression, updating the grid etc we're kind of in the dark here

Comment: @sab669 see the comment

Comment: Look at the link I shared in my original comment and try setting the `filterexpression`, `OnFiltering`, and `filterparameters` as they do in their Example.

Comment: Yeah tried that, I found what the error was but it's still not filtering it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @MariaL - Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yeah thanks, it did work but I'm now trying to actually do it all with one dropdown. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering the records obviously the first change you will have to do in the `NamesData` such that it accepts a parameter and return filtered records.

Next, add the parameter with `SelectParameters` tag in your ObjectDataSource control like this:-

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="Names"  
      SelectMethod="NamesData">
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" DefaultValue=""
                 Name="personName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here, `personName` is the name of the parameter you will add to the `NamesData` method. Also, you have to set the `DefaultValue` accordingly so that you can see all the records in initial page load.